# Hat not showing on site meta

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, per-site-meta, winter-bash-2013

I've selected my hat, it's showing up great on my user profile and on my posts on the main site:

[image]

but it isn't showing up on the site's meta:

[image]

but it **is** showing up on this Meta (as you can see below). Is this a bug, or just a timing issue? (note I've done multiple full refreshes of the page).

Comment: Per site child metas do not have a capital M in their meta

Comment: @Emracool It shows up fine on this Meta, but not on the specific site meta, as at this moment you can see it here: [check this post](http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/336/70)

Comment: You don't have a profile on the per site child metas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to take your hat off when visiting child metas.

Comment: You can't argue with logic like that :)

Comment: But why? Children love hats. Or maybe they liked it so much that they asked you for it. You can't say no to children. ;)

Comment: @BleedingFingers I am *very* good at saying no to children. ;)

Comment: This is not true now. See related [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289262/339911). Hats visible on meta sites for web.