# Hats not showing for meta sites in iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, meta, winter-bash

Can't see any hat for any post on meta sites in the iOS app. Tested on:

- meta.ru.stackoverflow.com
- meta.stackoverflow.com

Except for meta.stackexchange.com

My profile page in the iOS app on:

- ruSO:

  > [image: ruSO]
- meta.ruSO:

  > [image: meta.ruSO]

Web profile looks identical (in terms of hats):

- [main](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut?tab=profile)
- [meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut?tab=profile)

My post is not a dup of [suggested question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288342/339911) because relevant only for iOS app. I can see hats via web on meta sites. My question is not about earning, but showing hats.

---

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: @Glorfindel post updated.

Comment: Hats have been a bit inconsistent on the app, there was a few days when I couldn't see any hats at all, occasionally I've had the wrong hats (there's a dupe for that somewhere), all is showing fine now though...

Comment: Sorry, I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: Possible duplicate, or at least related: [Hat inconsistencies in iOS app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288531/hat-inconsistencies-in-ios-app)